# FactoryGirl without DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a legacy database that my ruby on rails application is hitting to get some data and I want to write some tests around some functionality. I don't have migrations since this database is another department's responsibility.

I have FactoryGirl set up for the AR Model that I'd like to test. I use the `build_stubbed` method but it seems that Rails or Rspec is obsessed with trying to connect to the database even though I don't want to save anything.

Every time I run a test I get this error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "yourTable" does not exist
         ^
```

Like I stated before, my goal isn't to save anything I just want to be able to test some of the functionality without really interacting with the peristence layer at all.

How do I configure Rspec/FactoryGirl to let me not connect to the database at all for these particular models?

Comment: I don't know that you can: ActiveRecord talks to the database to find out what the names and types of the the columns are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using the Struct class instead? I don't think FactoryGirl will allow you to create stubs without an existing table but you *could* try assigning a Struct to a constant in your test if the table doesn't already exist in Rails.

```
YourTable = Struct.new(:column_name1, :column_name2)
instance_of_table = YourTable.new(value1, value2)

instance_of_table.column_name1 => value1
```

[This article by Philip Brown](http://culttt.com/2015/04/15/working-with-structs-in-ruby/) goes into more detail about the use of Structs and OpenStructs so hopefully that will be helpful as well.

Comment: The only problem would be duplication to test the methods in those objects? Any suggestion on that? I'm not opposed with the strict approach.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean unfortunately. If you use a Struct, the object created will only exist in memory for the duration of the test. If you use FactoryGirl's create method, then objects created will be saved to the test environment (which is a separate database) but there are tools that can be used to remove them after each test is run if necessary (the [database_cleaner gem](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) might come in handy or you could remove them manually using an after hook in RSpec). I'm not sure if you'd have to worry about duplicates in the database.